# JjQuery & transform-origin

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I am trying to make a css 3D transform menu with a dynamic  perspective and rotation on jquery and a transform-origin just to explore dramatic effects, sadly i´m not sure where I failed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainWrapper').on("mousemove", function(event) {
    var menuWidth = document.getElementById('mainMenu').offsetWidth;
    var x = event.pageX * 100 / menuWidth;
    var origin = Math.floor(x) + "%;"
    var angle = (x * -30 / 100) + 15;
    $("#mainMenu").css({
      "-webkit-transform-origin": origin,
      "-moz-transform-origin": origin,
      "-ms-transform-origin": origin,
      "transform-origin": origin,
      "transform": " perspective(" + menuWidth / 6 + "px)  rotateY(" + angle + "deg)"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainWrapper">
  <nav id="mainMenu" class="mainMenu">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
      <div class="cell round"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The transforms happen without errors. Where does it fail for you?

Comment: Hello
Supposedly ... my "origin" variable must have a percentage value of my cursor x ... so, if my cursor is on the left side the transformation origin must be to the left of the screen and so on.
But it seems that the origin is always in the center
As you said apparently doesnt happen errors, but the "transform-origin" property is never embedded in the style attribute of my tag unlike my property "transform"
and i dont know why...

Comment: Did the answer below workout for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple syntax error.

`var origin = Math.floor(x) + "%;"`

should be

`var origin = Math.floor(x) + "%"`.

In the `$.css()` function you are not setting the `string` in the `style` attribute directly but the function does it for you. `Math.floor(x) + "%"` is the argument of that function. The semicolon will be added by that function, when the `style` attribute string is set by the function.

When a css property you modify doesn't apply to the style attribute of an html element,
check syntax errors in your property then the function that applies them.
Print all values or objects to your console related to your operation.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be `transformOrigin` not `transform-origin` when using the jQuery `.css` function